# Mach-O File Error. Cannot Export Archive For Development Testing

Tags: xcode, mach-o

I started getting this issue trying to distribute an archive for my ios app.  The app is build on ionic3 framework.

Steps I have taken:

1. Build the app in ionic

   - Build the App and Archive in XCode
   - In the organizer, I try to export the archive for Development

On the next step, I get the error: 
main bundle ice-sports.app doesn't have a main Mach-O file. Same message appears in the standard.log
[image: Error Message]

Does anyone have any idea how to address this issue?  I have been looking for hours, but not sure what the resolution is

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just came across this myself.
make sure your Info.plist does contain a valid CFBundleExecutable:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>REPLACE_WITH_NAME_OF_YOUR_EXECUTABLE</string>
```